# Call C++ class method stored in a DLL

Tags: c++, class, methods, dll

When calling a class method that is loaded from a dll the 'this' pointer  changes in my application when I call that function.  In my example, the error happens at the line "if (Func2) return (*Func2)( s );"   In the debugger the program finds Func2 in the DLL and I can step through Func2, but it's not seeing the class instance that I expect. 
I want to avoid __declspec (dllimport/export) if possible and use a model definition file, even it is for understanding how this works.
It sounds like a simple change in either the DEF file, the calling of the function or its declaration should do the trick, but I've tried several permutations of the code without success. Can someone please tell me what the correct method is?

Thanks for your help!

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string.h>

namespace Mine
{
class B
{
public:
    int Func1 ( wchar_t * );
    int Func2 ( wchar_t * );
    int Counter = 0;
};

int B::Func1 ( wchar_t *s )
{
    HINSTANCE hdll = 0;
    typedef int ( __cdecl *TthisFunc2 )(wchar_t *);
    if ( hdll = LoadLibrary ( L"MyDll.dll" ) )
    {
        TthisFunc2 Func2 = ( TthisFunc2 ) GetProcAddress ( hdll, "Func2" );
        if ( Func2 ) return (*Func2) ( s );
    }
    return 0;
};

extern "C" int main ( )
{
    B b;
    int l = b.Func1 ( L"First call" );
    l +=  b.Func1 (L"Last call" );
    return l;
}
}


/////////////  In MyDll.dll
namespace Mine
{
int B::Func2 ( wchar_t *s )
{
    return Counter += (s ? wcslen(s) : 0);
}
}

//In MyDLL module definition file

//EXPORTS Func2
```

Comment: Your DLL and application need to be compiled with the same settings, uses the same runtime library, etc.  Any deviation, expect none of this to work.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how come you want to avoid using declspec export/import?

Comment: Doesn't the combination of LoadLibrary / GetProcessAddress give more flexibility in case of a missing library or missing function?